# Installing the Parse.com SDK for PHP

Tags: php, parse-platform, composer-php

I'm trying to install the Parse SDK for PHP. I've followed all the steps in the Quick Start manual, PHP runtime is installed (`PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14`), Composer is installed (`1.0-dev`), and I've created a file named `composer.json` in my project dir with the content specified in the manual, but when I run `php composer.phar install` its giving me this:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                  
Could not parse version constraint ~1.1.*: Invalid version string "~1.1.*"
```

I'm not familiar with PHP so its probably something stupid but I can't find anything online about this error that could send me in the right direction. Ideas?

Comment: I just copied that from the manual. I'm totally unfamiliar with composer so I have no idea. These are the contents of the composer.json file:

{

  "require" : {

    "parse/php-sdk" : "~1.1.*"
  }
}

Comment: And I've just tried removing the trailing `.` but same error.

Comment: Seems like One_Up is only one except me who is doing Parse+PHP development. #asking #commenting #answering -_*

Answer (score 3):

I've removed the leading `~` in the `composer.json` file and now it's working. Don't understand why that's in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Something Wrong with Parse Server But Try this, It Works:

> remove the ~ in the composer.json

```
{
"require" : {
    "parse/php-sdk" : "1.1.*"
}}
```